# How do I change the opacity of Ionic scrollbar?

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I'm building a webapp using the ionic.min.css styles. I'm trying to modify the opacity of the scrollbar (which is hardly visible now), and I believe this is the code I'm looking for...

```
.scroll-bar-indicator {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s linear;
    transition: opacity .3s linear
}
```

I supposed the background is the place to change it, but it seems to have no effect whatsoever. Am I in the right place? Thanks.

The page can be seen here:
http://www.linccomputing.com/demo/test/test.php

Comment: Have you tried changing the `opacity` property value? It accepts values from 0 to 1.

Comment: If you provide sample code, we might be able to track other CSS that could cause trouble. You can try posting a URL to your site, or a jsFiddle, codepen, etc.

Comment: @TylerH Yeah I have tried, to no effect.

Comment: @vic3685 Link to page added, thanks a lot.